# Join a video with audio with another video without audio and add audio to the second with watermark

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I have this ffmpeg command that works fine:

```
        ffmpeg -i main-video.mp4 -i bg-audio-main-video.mp3 -i watermark.png \
        -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:720,setsar=1:1,fps=25[Scaled];\
            [Scaled][2]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-(main_w*0.01):y=main_h-overlay_h-(main_h*0.01):format=yuv444[v2];\
            [v2]fade=t=out:st=$FADE_OUT_START:d=$FADE_OUT_DURATION[outv]" \
        -map "[outv]" -map 1:a -shortest \
        -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv444p \
        out.mp4
    ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -i out.mp4 -filter_complex \
        "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [outv] [outa]" \
        -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" output.mp4
```

But I want to join them in a single command, and this command the second audio is added to the main video, but is not cut off (it doesn't fits the time of the video), and I want it to fit the main video:

```
ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -i main-video.mp4 -i bg-audio-main-video.mp3 -i watermark.png \
    -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1280:720,setsar=1:1,fps=25[Scaled];\
    [Scaled]drawtext=/home/luismi/.local/share/fonts/Anton.ttf:text='$telf $City':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-text_h-20:fontsize=60:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxborderw=5:boxcolor=black@0.5[bg];\
    [bg][3]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-(main_w*0.01):y=main_h-overlay_h-(main_h*0.01):format=yuv444[outv];\
    [2:a]volume=enable='between(t,0,32)':volume=-3dB[2a];\
    [0:v][0:a][outv][2a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vid][aud]"\
    -map "[vid]" -map "[aud]" -shortest \
    -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv444p \
    output.mp4
```

I have tried different options and I can't find the solution. What should I adjust to achieve this goal?

Comment: I think the issue is related to `concat` with `a=1[vid][aud]`. Please remove the filters that are not relevant to the question (like `scale`, `drawtext` and `volume`). The sentence "the second audio that is added to the main video is not cut off (it doesn't fits the time of the video), and I want it to fit the main video" is unclear. Can you add a diagram?

Comment: I have an error, bg-audio-main-video is a mp3.

The intro.mp4 video has both audio and video, and the main-video.mp4 has only video, and to this I want to add bg-audio-main-video.mp3. bg-audio-main-video.mp3 is longer than main-video.mp4 and I want to adjust it (cut it off), and do it all in one ffmpeg command.
Thanks

Comment: I didn't notice you have two files with audio. You are concatenating `[0:a]` and `[2a]`, and this is OK.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but what happens is that the bg-audio-main-video.mp3 that is added to the main-video.mp4 doesn't fit the video size. That is, the audio is added with the total duration, and what I want is for it to be added with the duration of the video.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible with one command. But I am still not sure what you are asking. Try to draw it somehow (you may draw the timeline with characters like `########` `############` ... or `VVVVVVVVVV` `AAAAAAA` ....)

Comment: I'm currently using two commands to get what I want, and was looking for a way to do it with one.

Example:
The duration of intro.mp4 + main-video.mp4 is for example 2 minutes.
The audio length of intro.mp4 + bg-audio-main-video.mp3 is 10 minutes.

Instead of outputting a 2 minute video with audio intro.mp4 + bg-audio-main-video.mp3, the result is a 10 minute video.

Comment: Post the two commands you are currently using. Add a drawing anyway... Share the input files if you can. I see if I can find a solution.

Comment: I have put the two commands used in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could find is using the output pipe of one FFmpeg as input pipe of another FFmpeg.

In order to avoid re-encoding, the first FFmpeg output is raw video and raw audio (in AVI format).

```
ffmpeg -i main-video.mp4 -i bg-audio-main-video.mp3 -i watermark.png \
-filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:720,setsar=1:1,fps=25[Scaled];\
    [Scaled][2]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-(main_w*0.01):y=main_h-overlay_h-(main_h*0.01):format=yuv444[v2];\
    [v2]fade=t=out:st=$FADE_OUT_START:d=$FADE_OUT_DURATION[outv]" \
-map "[outv]" -map 1:a -shortest \
-c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -c:a pcm_s16le -f avi pipe: | \    
ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -vsync passthrough -i pipe: -filter_complex \
    "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [outv] [outa]" \
    -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" output.mp4
```

---

I have tested the solution (in Windows 10) without the `fade` filter:

`ffmpeg -i main-video.mp4 -i bg-audio-main-video.mp3 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:720,setsar=1:1,fps=25[Scaled];[Scaled][2]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-(main_w*0.01):y=main_h-overlay_h-(main_h*0.01):format=yuv444[outv]" -shortest -map "[outv]" -map 1:a -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -c:a pcm_s16le -f avi pipe: | ffmpeg -y -i intro.mp4 -vsync passthrough -i pipe: -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [outv] [outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" output.mp4`

---

Adding the `-vsync passthrough` argument is required:

> -vsync parameter
> Video sync method.
> passthrough (0)
> Each frame is passed with its timestamp from the demuxer to the muxer.